# Transform a PC into a network projector

Tags: windows-7, projector

We have a Windows 7 PC that is located in the conference room on which a TV is connected. I would like to transform this PC into a network projector, so that whenever a client or supplier comes in to the conference room with his laptop, he could connect to it via Wi-Fi and display his laptop screen on the TV.

We currently have an old version of a [Warpia product](http://www.warpia.com/products/streamhd-swp120a) that allows us to connect a laptop to the TV, but it requires a few drivers to be installed on the laptop, so this is basically a no-no when it comes to client laptops.

I saw this [program from Screen-Record](http://www.screen-record.com/projector_online.htm), but it doesn't seem to be available to purchase anymore. I didn't try the trial.

Is there is any way to transform a PC into a virtual network projector that would allow anybody to painlessly connect to it without requiring a user intervention on the projector PC?

Comment: My guess is that this simply isn't possible.  The no-driver requirement basically eliminates almost any possibility not built to the OS.

Comment: Curious what your objection is to using a hardware solution? Is it that the laptop may not have a VGA out? Or that you don't want to run wires from the laptop to the TV? If the latter, you could get something like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Wi-Fi-Wireless-Audio-Sender-connector/dp/B0076P0LA6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1353354701&sr=8-1&keywords=vga+to+wifi)... (I'd leave this as a comment rather than an answer, but I don't yet have comment rights.)

Comment: Well, if it is like installing a network printer, then this is OK. Installing the Warpia USB takes about 15 minutes (seriously) and leaves a bunch of icon running in the systray.

Comment: The room isn't made to accept wires in the middle of the table. We would have to run the cable on the ground which could be a safety hazard (unless taped). Regarding the warpia USB (which is hardware), it is a real PITA to use. See my comment on my question.

Comment: Okay, then it sounds like the thingy I linked to (or something like it) might work.  Basically if you can get an adapter that presents itself to the laptop as a standard VGA (or HDMI, or whatever) display, then that hardware device could do the wireless communication with the TV or the other computer or whatever, and the laptop wouldn't need any drivers.  I didn't check whether the adapter I linked to needs an external power supply, though, which would make it useless in this situation.

Comment: Windows 7 has a "Connect to a network projector" feature (I'm googling now to find out how to host a network project and wound up here...)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Windows Embedded Compact 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/develop/windows-embedded-compact-7-for-developers-overview.aspx) with Template Network Videoprojector.

Comment: Hi Seb. Links are not considered full answers. Care to add more detail?

Answer (score 1):

While I havn't had time to try it, [FYXM Online Projector](http://downloads.fyxm.net/Projector-Online-49067.html) seems to do exactly what you request.

You install it on your host computer and then any networked computer (vista and up) can use the OS feature to connect to a wireless projector.

Comment: Well, a search for Projector Online 1.5 on Google returns a lot of "how to uninstall". That doesn't give a lot of confidence in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a VNC running is listening mode solve your problem?

You install a listening viewer on the TV PC.

You start the VNC server on the client machine.

The viewer listens to it and automatically displays the output on the TV.

http://www.tightvnc.com/winst.php

> Add New Client... - This allows outgoing connections to be made from the server to a viewer started in the "listening" mode. The name of the target viewer machine and optional display number can be entered in the dialog. Connections created this way are treated as shared. Such so called "reverse connections" can also be initiated from the command line using the -connect option.
>
> Alternatively, you can start the viewer in the listening mode, by using the correspoding button in the "New Connection" window. In that mode, the viewer's icon will appear in the system tray, and it will accept reverse connections from TightVNC servers (see above the description of the WinVNC "Add New Client" menu item).

Comment: Good idea, I will try that Monday at work.